# KeyListener java, executes button's action

Tags: java, button, keylistener, keypad

Is there a method in Java that executes an action button is pressed?, I need this because I want to make a KeyListener that when you press a button on the keypad '5 'launched me button in the gui description '5';

EDIT

i got ActionListener with :

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
    if(button.getLabel().equals("1")){
     // do something
    }
 }
```

and KeyListener with

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
  if (e.getKeyCode() == VK_NUMPAD1) {
        //    do what would happen if I pressed the mouse on the button
        //    I do not know how to execute it thought that it was pressing down the 
        // button with the label '1 '
  }
}
```

Comment: unclear what you asking.what did you tried?

Comment: Yes, it's called a KeyListener. The problem is probably either the component you bind this listener to (when it's active) or the key code you use for the keypad. Show some code.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html or http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyAdapter.html, whether you prefer anonymous inner classes or interfaces.

Example:

```
panel.add(new KeyListener() {
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == VK_NUMPAD5) {
            // do whatever you want here
            System.out.println("Numpad 5 pressed);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
});
```

or

```
panel.add(new KeyAdapter() {
    // override the method you want
    // do what you want here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The below example is fine, all you have to put inside the if sentence is:

```
if (e.getKeyCode() == VK_NUMPAD5) {
    nameOfButtonToClick.doClick();
}
```

Obviously they have to be within the same scope which it should anyway since your buttons are probably declared as field values?